# Building an engine in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, data-integration

Basically I want to create an engine that reads in all data sources and pushes them out. I'll need to use a flag to turn applications on and off and a sequence column to adjust which is running first. It will be a file based repository.

Does anyone have any useful ideas or links on how I would go about doing this?

**I am reading in an excel file with applications as the field.
I have copied rows to result, but i want to output multiple excel files with each application name as the name of the excel file. So each row would become the name of the excel file**
 Not sure how to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no "Universal Input" or "Universal Output" steps yet in PDI, so you will have to be a lot more specific about what you want to achieve and just how generic it needs to be.

Comment: edited with more details

Comment: And what will the contents of each Excel file be, rows from the input Excel or from some other data source?

Comment: the rows will be blank... or an alternative would be to loop through the application name and output to log or text file to show that it's actually looping through the rows if that makes sense?

Comment: never mind, i've managed to do it